Falla en recuperar datos en query de Eloquent
Tengo una serie de tablas con sus respectivas relaciones en Laravel 8, tengo una tabla properties que tiene su relacion con una llamada utilities, y esta a su vez con otra llamada connections, una API retorna los datos de las utilities, que tienen alguna entrada en connections y a las que se usa un id de properties para hacer la llamada porque las utilities pertenecen a un property, y las connections a un utility, entonces para retornar las connections en Laravel es comodo utilizar un query del tipo:
  $query = $property->utilities()
           ->with('connections.utility');

esto en teoria debe regresar aquellas entradas en connections que estan ligadas a un utility y que a su vez estan ligadas a un property.
Pero tengo un comportamiento extraño y no pude determinar de donde vendria el error, en un caso esa query me esta regresando 2 entradas, pero hay 3 en la tabla, cuando hago un select en property_uuid en utilities, tengo 3 utilities, y cuando hago un select en connections con cada utility_uuid tengo una entrada para cada uno, pero me esta regresando solo 2.
Despues de confirmar los modelos y hacer la prueba solo con el SQL al final llegue a una solucion alternativa con:
   $query = $property->utilities()
              ->select('utilities.*', 'connections.*')
              ->join('connections', 'connections.utility_uuid', '=', 'utilities.utility_uuid');

Que hace lo mismo, busca los utilities que tienen un match entre connections y utilities haciendo un join, pero me quedé con la duda de porque fallaria el primero?

tienes la relacion creada correctamente? algo que la gente olvida es que puedes especificar las columnas involucradas  "$this->belongsTo((Utility::class, 'utility_uuid', 'utility_uuid');"

Si esta, en Connection model:
public function utility()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Utility::class, 'utility_uuid', 'utility_uuid');
  }


¿Qué es $property en tu código?

$property es la instancia del Modelo Property, $property = Property::where('property_uuid', $request->input('property_uuid'));
